# Getting post parameters with characters that are not allowed to be used in a variable with web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I am trying to integrate google reCaptcha into my site, when I realized the POST parameter it required to get submitted had a character that isn't legal "e.g. the minus operator sign.

Here is the code from the projects:

```
class apply:
    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()        

        print recaptcha2.verify("mySecretKey",i.g-recaptcha-response, "end user's ip")
```

The problem I am having relates to the g-recaptcha-response POST parameter and how it is a variable with characters that are not legal to use in variables with python.

Is there a work-around with this?

Update:
Here is an example of the error I am facing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 236, in process
    return self.handle()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 227, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 409, in
_delegat e
    return handle_class(cls)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 384, in handle_c lass
    return tocall(*args)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Web App - Copy\bin\app.py", line 42, in P OST
    print recaptcha2.verify("mySecretKey", i.g-recaptcha-response, us_ip)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\utils.py", line 76, in \__getattr__
    raise AttributeError, k AttributeError: 'g'

myServerIP - - [27/Jun/2015 05:20:23] "HTTP/1.1 POST /apply_check" - 5 00 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Can you show us the errors? Can you print out the POST dict?

Comment: Sure, I included the errors in the post, the main error was that it is trying to a variable g out of variable i (an instance of web.input()) and then subtract variables recaptcha and response, but g-recaptcha-resonse is what google is sending as a post value to the server, so I need to get this POST value, but cant as the variable name that the post value would be stored under is an invalid variable.

Comment: I don't know `web.py`, but have you tried 1/ printing `dir(i)` to see what attributes are actually available that you can use? 2/ see if you can use dictionary accessing (something like `i['g-recaptcha-response']`), since the [web.py cookbook mentions](http://webpy.org/cookbook/input) that `web.input()` returns a dictionary like object.

Comment: The comment above was successful in getting the POST data by referencing the post name to an instance of web.input()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve getting the POST data sent as g-recaptcha-response by referencing it in a variable that was a web.input() object
e.g.

```
i = web.input()
i['g-recaptcha-response']
```